# Change image when light/dark mode on gmail

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, darkmode

I'm trying to change an Image logo in Gmail template. The only solution that I've found is to add translucent outline to transparent PNGs and set `background` white as basic and the color invert will change it to black, or `drop-shadow` on the image. Is there a way around this issue to check if `prefers-color-scheme` is dark/light without using the query? and then render a different image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.